# How to serialize/deserialize std::map<int, MyObject> to/from json in C++

Tags: c++, json, c++11, nlohmann-json

I'm trying to serialize/deserialize `std::map<int, MyObject>` using https://github.com/nlohmann/json

It says [here](https://github.com/nlohmann/json#conversion-from-stl-containers) that the keys for the map must be able to generate `std::string`. How can I achieve that?

Basic usage for implementing conversion to/from my custom object `MyObject` would be:

```
using nlohmann::json;

namespace ns {
    void to_json(json& j, const MyObject& p) {
        j = json{{"name", p.name}, {"address", p.address}, {"age", p.age}};
    }

    void from_json(const json& j, MyObject& p) {
        j.at("name").get_to(p.name);
        j.at("address").get_to(p.address);
        j.at("age").get_to(p.age);
    }
} // namespace ns
```

however what should I do for the map?  The last thing I want to do is implement `void to_json(json& j, const std::map<int, MyObject>& p)` and `void from_json(const json& j, std::map<int, MyObject>& p)` . Since the library already supports `std::map`, it should do everything for me, I just need to convert the `int` to `std::string`. How can I do just that?

Comment: Not familiar with that particular library, but one particular workaround would be a light wrapper for an `int` value that also implements an `operator std::string`. This seems like a strange limitation. According  to the documentation, it's not a problem for map values to be integers, and it'll serialize them. I can't immediately see the problem with using `int`s as map/list keys in json.

Comment: The key wording in the documentation is _"whose keys can __construct__ an `std::string`"_. There is no `std::string` constructor that accepts an `int` value, which is why it doesn't work.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik It's not a problem for values to be integers because JSON has a native numeric type. That case _must_ be handled for the implementation to even make any sense. However, object keys cannot be integers; they must be strings. The library author apparently chose to require that keys can be explicitly converted to `std::string`, however in C++ `int` is not explicitly convertible to `std::string`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wording in the readme is clear as to why this doesn't work (emphasis mine):

> Likewise, any associative key-value containers ... whose keys can **construct** an `std::string` and whose values can be used to construct JSON values ... can be used to create a JSON object.

This is why using `int` as a key doesn't work with this library; an `std::string` cannot be constructed from an `int`.

---

The natural follow-up question is *why* this isn't allowed. This is something you would have to ask the author of the library for a definitive answer.

We could speculate that it's because there is no one way to convert an integral to a string. Perhaps assume a base 10 representation with no leading zeros would be a reasonable choice, but there is no compelling reason why this must be the only choice.

What about hex-encoded strings, or scientific notation, or thousands separators, or any possible number of other options?

Another possible reason is that integral keys suggest a sparse array, so it may be unclear whether you are requesting an object or an array be produced in the output.

---

A possible solution would be to build a helper that converts any map to an `std::map<std::string, TValue>` by running the keys through `std::to_string()`:

```
// Copy variant
template <typename T>
std::map<std::string, typename T::mapped_type> to_string_keyed_map(T const & input) {
    std::map<std::string, typename T::mapped_type> output;

    for (auto const & pair : input) {
        output.emplace(std::to_string(pair.first), pair.second);
    }

    return output;
}

// Move variant
template <typename T>
std::map<std::string, typename T::mapped_type> to_string_keyed_map(T && input) {
    std::map<std::string, typename T::mapped_type> output;

    for (auto & pair : input) {
        output.emplace(std::to_string(pair.first), std::move(pair.second));
    }

    return output;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to transform the map into an array of pairs of number and [object in json format]?

Comment: Somebody indeed made this behavior work without modifying anything: https://github.com/nlohmann/json/issues/739 but I dont get it working for mine

Answer (score 0):

Here's a generic solution: define `to_json()` and `from_json()` function templates for arbitrary `std::map` as follows:

```
template <typename KTy, typename VTy> inline
void to_json(nlohmann::json& j, const std::map<KTy, VTy>& m)
{
    using std::to_string;
    for (const auto& e : m)
    {
        j[to_string(e.first)] = e.second;
    }
}

template <typename KTy, typename VTy> inline
void from_json(const nlohmann::json& j, std::map<KTy, VTy>& m)
{
    for (const auto& e : j.items())
    {
        KeyTy k;
        from_string(e.key(), k);
        auto v = e.value().get<VTy>();
        m[k] = v;
    }
}
```

Now we have define a way to convert string values to our map's `key_type` ("deserialize" the keys). For example, it can be achieved with a `from_string()` function template like this:

```
// A generic implementation (stub).
template <typename Ty> inline
void from_string(const std::string& key, Ty& value)
{
    value = key;
}

template <> inline
void from_string(const std::string& key, int& value)
{
    char* endPtr = nullptr;
    val = std::strtol(key.c_str(), &endPtr, 10);
}
// Add more specializations for other key types here.
```

Having these functions in place, and `to`/`from_json()` overloads for custom types (from the original question), one can convert `std::map` to and from JSON the natural way:

```
nlohmann::json j;
std::map<int, MyObject> myMap;
// ...
myMap = j.at("inputs").get<std::map<int, MyObject>>();
j = myMap;
```